# text input problems? jquery/html?

Tags: jquery, html

I wish I could post code about what is wrong, but frankly, I dont know. My web page works, but the input elements in the contact panel won't allow me to enter anything. any idea why?

http://s1527.mtchs.org

Comment: Fixing `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://s1527.mtchs.org/hide.js` would be a good place to start

Comment: Looks like you need to get intimate with Developer Tools

Comment: Also, please validate your markup: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fs1527.mtchs.org%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS http://s1527.mtchs.org/techmuffins.css

The first rule contains declarations that will render everything (`*`) "unselectable", specifically the collection of (cross-browser) variants of the [`user-select` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/user-select).

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none; /****************************/
    -webkit-user-select: none;   /* Remove these lines       */
    -khtml-user-select: none;    /* or make the CSS selector */
    -moz-user-select: none;      /* more specific to avoid   */
    -ms-user-select: none;       /* the <input/> elements    */
    user-select: none;           /****************************/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These rules are the reason you can't select the inputs.

```
* {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```